# make drop-down fields dependent of each other

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I set-up a form with with project details and want to implement several drop-down options to filter project properties. These are "project-name", "customer" and "product". I want to make them dependent on each other. So when I select a particular customer, I only want to be able to choose from products which are related to the customer.

So far I was able to set-up each drop-down for each project property but they are not dependet of each other, but always show all available options. Can someone help me out with dependent drop-down fields?

[Selection fields as they are now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suje8.png)

Edit: Table layout upon request:

Rows/format 
-Project ID/Number
-Customer/String
-Product/String
-Project-name/String
-Comment/String
-Feature 1/String

Comment: Can you please post your table layout - are there separate tables for each of these?

Comment: Added the table layout. Hope this clarifies things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this to to use "cascading" combo boxes, so the user moves from the top combo box towards the bottom one, each time narrowing the range available to them.

Your VBA code would look something like this:

```
Private Sub cboCustomer_AfterUpdate()
    Dim strSQL As String
    If Len(Me!cboCustomer) > 0 Then
        strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Product FROM tblProject " _
            & " WHERE Customer='" & Me!cboCustomer & "' " _
            & " ORDER BY Product ASC;"
        Me!cboProduct.RowSource = strSQL
    Else
        strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Product FROM tblProject ORDER BY Product ASC;"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cboProject_AfterUpdate()
    Dim strSQL As String
    If Len(Me!cboProject) > 0 Then
        strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Customer FROM tblProject " _
            & " WHERE ProjectID=" & Me!cboProject _
            & " ORDER BY Customer ASC;"
        Me!cboCustomer.RowSource = strSQL
        strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Product FROM tblProject " _
            & " WHERE ProjectID=" & Me!cboProject _
            & " ORDER BY Product ASC;"
        Me!cboProduct.RowSource = strSQL
    Else
        Me!cboCustomer.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT Customer FROM tblProject ORDER BY Customer ASC;"
        Me!cboProduct.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT Product FROM tblProject ORDER BY Product ASC;"
    End If
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! I guess i put this in each of my drop-down fields as the "selection-event" ?

Comment: You use the "AfterUpdate" event for the combo boxes for Project (the first choice) and then Customer (the second choice).

Comment: Unfortunately all I got are empty combo boxes.

Comment: You will need to set the RowSource of the Project combo box to be `SELECT ProjectID, ProjectName FROM tblProject ORDER BY ProjectName`, and also the Column Count to be 2, with Column Widths of "0;4.9cm" in the Form's design view.

Comment: cool thanks-now the column is populated with the Project ID number and no longer empty. I get other errors now, but I might have some syntax issues somwhere I need 2 look into. Will report back

Comment: Alright - now i can select the Project Name from the cboProject, but when I try to select the customer from cboCustomer i get "syntax error (missing operator) in query "Project ID = Project001" "

Comment: I thought that ProjectID was a number? Anyway, you will need to change the WHERE part of the SQL statements to `WHERE ProjectID=' " & Me!cboProject & " ' "` (I've left spaces between the single and double quotes for visibility, but you don't need them in your code).

Comment: Yes "Project ID" is a number. It's an Integer and counting up individually. - Edit: I seem to have changed the "bound column" to "2". I changed it back to "1" again and now i got the same error saying "syntax error (missing operator) in query Project ID = 10"

Comment: What columns are in the combobox for the Projects, and what is the bound column?

Comment: I seem to, as stated in my comment above, have erroneously bound the 1st column, but changed it to 2 since

Comment: If it is not working, please do a `Debug.Print strSQL` after the SQL statement is created, and then post the SQL statement that is shown in the immediate window.

Comment: Sorry to inconvenience you.. i tried putting Debug.Print strSQL after the End If statement for the cboProject but how would i go about the immediate window?

Comment: When you are a module, press Ctl+G.